# Changing the default behavior of Kubernetes

Tags: configuration, kubernetes

I have setup a K8S cluster (1 master and 2 slaves) using Kubeadm on my laptop.

- Deployed 6 replicas of a pod. 3 of them got deployed to each of the slaves.
- Did a shutdown of one of the slave.
- It took ~6 minutes for the 3 pods to be scheduled on the running node.

Initially, I thought that it had to do something with the K8S setup. After some digging found out, it's because of the defaults in the K8S for Controller Manager and Kubelet as mentioned [here](https://fatalfailure.wordpress.com/2016/06/10/improving-kubernetes-reliability-quicker-detection-of-a-node-down/). It made sense. I checked out the K8S documentation on where to change the configuration properties and also checked the configuration files on the cluster node, but couldn't figure it out.

```
kubelet: node-status-update-frequency=4s (from 10s)
controller-manager: node-monitor-period=2s (from 5s)
controller-manager: node-monitor-grace-period=16s (from 40s)
controller-manager: pod-eviction-timeout=30s (from 5m)
```

Could someone point out what needs to be done to make the above-mentioned configuration changes permanent and also the different options for the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the kubelet change this file on all your nodes:

```
/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env
```

Add the option at the end or anywhere on this line:

```
KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=cgroupfs --cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin 
--cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.d --network-plugin=cni 
--resolv-conf=/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf 
--node-status-update-frequency=10s <== add this
```

On your kube-controller-manager change on the master the following file:

```
/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml
```

In this section:

```
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-controller-manager
    - --address=127.0.0.1
    - --allocate-node-cidrs=true
    - --cloud-provider=aws
    - --cluster-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
    - --cluster-signing-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    - --cluster-signing-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.key
    - --controllers=*,bootstrapsigner,tokencleaner
    - --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
    - --leader-elect=true
    - --node-cidr-mask-size=24
    - --root-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    - --service-account-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key
    - --use-service-account-credentials=true
    - –-node-monitor-period=5s  <== add this line
```

On your master do a `sudo systemctl restart docker`
On all your nodes do a `sudo systemctl restart kubelet`

You should have the new configs take effect.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Rico - thanks for the response - I made the changes to the config files and restarted the daemons. The behavior was the same, the pods were scheduled on the healthy node in ~6min. I even restarted the master and worker OS, it's all the same.

Comment: I see. I believe your issue is not related to either `–-node-monitor-period` or `node-status-update-frequency` What makes you think it's related to that? My answer was for you to get those parameters configured.

Comment: If you are not sure, can you post `kubectl describe nodes`? also for the pods that are getting scheduled in 6 mins `kubectl describe <pod-name>`. Also if you can `docker logs kube-controller-manager`, and `docker logs kube-scheduler`. Feel free to make it into a new question.

Comment: Sure Rico - your answer address my query on configuring the parameters. I will look into why 6m and open a new query if required - Thanks

Comment: Note changes in kube-controller-manager.yaml [won't persist](https://www.rusinov.ie/en/posts/2021/things-i-learned-about-kubernetes-version-upgrades/) after cluster upragdes. You may want to modify kubeadm-config ConfigMap as well, e.g. via `kubectl -n kube-system edit ConfigMap/kubeadm-config`